# submitting / stop submitting form inside ajax success call

Tags: jquery

On the submit button click, I am calling an API. And if it returns true, i want to show error message and stop submitting form.
But if it returns false, I want to submit the form.

jquery code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        if ($('#EMail').val().length != 0) {

            var email = $('#EMail').val();
            var url = "url";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (responsedata) {
                    var result = $(responsedata).find("Exists").text();
                    console.log(result);
                    if (result == 'false') {
                        $('#frmsignup').submit();

                    } else {
                        //show error.
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {

                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });

        } else {
            $('#frmsignup').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

but the problem is with the above code even `if (result == 'true')`, the form gets submitted and error doesn't show up.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Recheck this value
`$('#EMail').val().length` and `alert(result);`

Answer (score 1):

first u have to stop the submit event on click of submit button

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

THen u can call .submit() of form whenever u want

Comment: now the form never gets submitted. I mean if result=true, i see the error message. but if result=false, the form doesn't submit

Answer (score 0):

I think, you problem is that you check if result == 'false', in this case 'false' is a string, but not bool.

```
if (!result) { 
   $('#frmsignup').submit();
} else {
   //show error
   return false;
}
```